# C# sorting two lists alphanumerically

Tags: c#

I have two lists where the first list are headers and the second list are values that corresponds to these headers. I will like to sort the headers alphanumerically but I do not know how I can solve this. Since the values in the second list needs to be sorted out accordingly. For example

```
var columns = new List<string> { "Name", "Age", "Height", "1stRegistration" };
var values  = new List<string> { "Bob", "27", "1.8", "01-01-2022" };
```

using the `Sort()` method on the list will produce the following result but how do i get the values to be sorted based on the results?

```
1stRegistration     ---> 01-01-2022 // expected values in the second list
Age                 ---> 27
Height              ---> 1.8
Name                ---> Bob
```

Comment: maybe if you had the values as a map like columnName => value it would be easier to get the value you need in values according to how you sorted the header

Comment: If you're using windows, you can try native [StrCmpLogicalW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strcmplogicalw)

Comment: You can get the second list by index of first list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest option is to pair these together before you sort. You can do this using LINQ:

```cs
var sorted = columns.Zip(values).OrderBy(x => x.First);

foreach (var (column, value) in sorted)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{column,-20} ---> {value}");
}
```

Output:

```
1stRegistration      ---> 01-01-2022
Age                  ---> 27
Height               ---> 1.8
Name                 ---> Bob
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `column` must correspond its `value` you can combine both lists

```
var columnAndValue = new List<(string column, string value)> {
  ("Name", "Bob"),
  ("Age", "27"),
  ("Height", "1.8"),
  ("1stRegistration", "01-01-2022"),
};
```

and then `Sort` as

```
columnAndValue.Sort((left, right) => left.column.CompareTo(right.column));
```

If you insist on having *two* lists, you can combine them temporary with a help of `Zip`:

```
var both = colums
  .Zip(values, (c, v) => (column : c, value : v))
  .OrderBy(pair => pair.value)
  .ToList();

colums.Clear();
values.Clear();

columns = both.AddRange(both.Select(pair => pair.column));
values = both.AddRange(both.Select(pair => pair.value));
```